# arccot limit: $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\cot ^{-1}(r^2+\frac{3}{4})$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, summation

I have to find the limit of this sum:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\cot ^{-1}(r^2+\frac{3}{4})$$

I tried using sandwich theorem , observing:

$$\cot ^{-1}(r^3)\leq\cot ^{-1}(r^2+\frac{3}{4})\leq\cot ^{-1}(r^2)$$

Now when I was calculating the limit of left hand expression, I convert it to $\tan^{-1}$, by using:
 $$\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x} = \cot^{-1}x$$

but couldn't sum up the terms of arctan series.

- How can I proceed?
- Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**

The general term can be written as
$$\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{r^2+3/4}$$
$$=\tan^{-1}\frac{r+1/2-(r-1/2)}{(r-1/2)(r+1/2)+1}$$
$$=\tan^{-1}(r+1/2)-\tan^{-1}(r-1/2)$$

Comment: Nice! What made you think that way? Thanks!

Comment: Also can we apply the sandwich theorem some way here?

Comment: @MaxPayne I doubt it..

Comment: He's trying to get you to see that it is a collapsing series.

Comment: @MaxPayne, $$r^2+\dfrac34=1+r^2-\left(\dfrac12\right)^2$$

Answer (score 3):

One may use
$$
\arctan a - \arctan b=\arctan \left(\frac{a-b}{1+ab} \right), \quad a,b \in \left[0,\frac\pi2\right],
$$ with
$$
a=\frac{2n-3}{4(n+1)},\quad b=\frac{2(n-1)-3}{4n}, \quad n=1,2,3,\ldots,
$$ giving, for $n \geq1$,
$$
\arctan \left(\frac{2n-3}{4(n+1)} \right)-\arctan \left(\frac{2(n-1)-3}{4n} \right)=\arctan \left(\frac1{n^2+\frac34} \right)
$$ then, by telescoping,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\arctan \left(\frac1{n^2+\frac34} \right)=\arctan \left(\frac{2N-3}{4(N+1)} \right)-\arctan \left(-\frac34 \right).
$$ Letting $N \to \infty$ gives

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\arctan \left(\frac1{n^2+\frac34} \right)=\arctan \left(\frac12 \right)+\arctan \left(\frac34 \right)=\arctan 2.
> $$