# Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, proof-verification, summation

> Find $$M:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{n^2}$$

There's a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427602/find-the-value-of-infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-tan-12-n2) that uses complex numbers which I didn't understand and I was wondering if the following is also a correct method.

My proposed solution

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{n^2}\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\frac{(1+n)+(1-n)}{1-(1+n)(1-n)}\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\tan^{-1}(1+n)+\tan^{-1}(1-n))\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\tan^{-1}(n-1))
\end{align}
$$

And this implies 
$$M=\lim_{m\to\infty}(\tan^{-1}(m+1)+\tan^{-1}m-\tan^{-1}1-\tan^{-1}0)=\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

Comment: This may or may not be of help: $\arctan(1/x) = \pi/2 - \arctan(x)$

Comment: The 3rd and 4th lines of the equation after "My proposed solution" are missing a summation sign. Otherwise, the solution is correct.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Edited, ty.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849546/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-cot-12n2       https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193001/explicitly-finding-the-sum-of-arctan1-n2n1  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794175/arccot-limit-sum-r-1-infty-cot-1r2-frac34

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{n^2}\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\frac{(1+n)+(1-n)}{1-(1+n)(1-n)}\\
=\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}&\tan^{-1}(1+n)+\tan^{-1}(1-n)\\
=\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}&\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\tan^{-1}(n-1)
\end{align}
$$

Edit:$\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}$ was missing in your question before edit. I am not going to delete this.

However your proof is now correct.
$$M=\lim_{m\to\infty}(\tan^{-1}(m+1)+\tan^{-1}m-\tan^{-1}1-\tan^{-1}0)=\color{red}{\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2-\frac\pi4-0=\pi-\frac\pi4}=\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. If I was going to offer a critique I would just say: when writing an argument it's always better to over communicate rather than under communicate.

The first equality is just algebra.

Your second equality requires a little bit to see clearly but it's true. Most will recall:

$$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1-\tan(A)\tan(B)}$$
Or if you'd like:
$$A+B= \tan^{-1} \bigg(\frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1-\tan(A)\tan(B)} \bigg)$$
Taking $A=\tan^{-1}(1+n)$ and $B=\tan^{-1}(1-n)$

Honestly adding this much explanation seems like almost overkill.

The 4th equality follows as result of $\tan^{-1}$ being an odd function.

Now the last part you are using a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) technique so that you may ignore all the middle terms. That is,

$$\begin{align} &\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\tan^{-1}(n-1) \\ 
&= \lim_{m\to \infty} \tan^{-1}(m+1)-tan^{-1}(m-1)+\dots +\tan^{-1}(4)-\tan^{-1}(2)+\tan^{-1}(3)-\tan^{-1}(1)+tan^{-1}(2)-\tan^{-1}(0)
\end{align}$$

So after we consider what cancels and what doesn't we find that we only need to concern ourselves with $$\lim_{m\to \infty}\tan^{-1}(m+1)+\tan^{-1}(m-1)-\tan^{-1}(1)$$

So while that is true: I think it might merit a sentence or two just to make sure the audience is following.

Comment: Isn't $M=\lim_{m\to \infty} \tan^{-1}(m)-\tan^{-1}(0)=\frac\pi2-0?$

Comment: @tatan. Yes. I am missing some terms. Let me edit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really slow at writing in latex so I skip steps. But I will add more explanation in English in the future.

Comment: I have (with @tatan 's help) just shown why a few extra sentences couldn't hurt here: I made an error in following this correctly with my first attempt.

Comment: I think you are still missing one term... Aren't you?

Comment: Yes. Now we are set? Finally.

Comment: Yep. Can I ask you one thing? Are you from Maryland?(I saw from your profile)

Comment: Yes. Uh oh. Stranger danger. :). No. I am not worried. I grew up in Ohio and move to the DC area post college. I went to Ohio University not Univ of Maryland. Though I did cite Dr. Yorke in my undergrad thesis and then I met him wandering once while wandering Univ of Maryland's halls...

Comment: That's great. I have heard a lot about Univ of Maryland and college park . No danger from this stranger ;-)

Comment: Oh... I see  ;-) Actually I had a physics teacher in high school who had visited Univ of Maryland on some academic visit. That's where I came to know about it...